# Remove extra white space from input in cakephp

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp-1.3

I have a html form to save projects in cakephp. i want to restrict the user to save same project name. If any body type the same project name for that i applied the 'unique' validation in model but if anybody enter the same name with spaces before or after the project name it accepts it and store into the database.THat is the issue. I want to remove that extra spaces before save.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as an addition to @Prasantn Bebdra's answer and since the asker doesn't know where and how to use `trim()`.

To trim all the data that is comming from POST in your controller (just before the call to `Model->save()`) do:

```
foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
    $this->data[$key] = trim($value);
}
```

You can also use this in the `Model` by utilizing one of it's [callbacks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html) for example [beforeValidate()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforevalidate) or [beforeSave()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave) where in your case it should be better to use beforeValidate since you'd probably also want to validate this data afterwards.

You should also notify the user that the input will be trimmed and maybe also do such trimming on the client-side (before the POST) - check [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8121031/840409) out.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Borislav Sabev..its very useful post for me.i used this in my model by using call back beforeValidate()..

Answer (score 8):

The best place to remove whitespace from user input i.e. `trim()` is in the `beforeFilter()` callback at the Controller level. For PHP5+ the array function `array_walk_recursive()` makes this job very easy.

For example:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();

    // remove leading and trailing whitespace from posted data
    if (!function_exists('trimItem')) {
        function trimItem(&$item,$key){
            if (is_string($item)){
                $item = trim($item);    
            }
        }
    }       
    array_walk_recursive($this->request->data, 'trimItem');                     
}
```

Drop this code into `AppController` and user input will be trimmed on all forms

Hope this helps

Comment: This approach works great. You could even improve it by using closure functions.

`// remove leading and trailing whitespace from posted data
array_walk_recursive($this->request->data, function (&$value,$key) {
 if (is_string($value)) {
  $value = trim($value);
 }
});`

sorry for bad code format in comments.

Answer (score 3):

use `trim` which will trim your string from both sides

ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
trim($str);
```

Comment: i want to trim all the data that is coming through POST, after submitting the form.

Comment: @AmandeepKaur yes you need to trim everything unless you expect user to enter a space

Comment: this is not resolved. in cake php when we submit the form then using cake;s save() function directly we can save the sll posted data. now where i can trim the fields???

Answer (score 0):

Through my research, I think the best solution if your data is in **array format** then try this => [Stackoverflow: How to trim white spaces of array values in php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762453/5038388)

While, if your data is **not an array** then you can simply use:

```
$data = trim($data);
```